# Tight spacing on badge numbers on Accounts list

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I don't know when this was changed, but I've noticed just now:

[image: smushed badges]

It happens with single-digit numbers as well:

[image: smushed single-digit badges]

The badge numbers are compressed together rather tightly. Inserting spacing between the columns would make it less confusing to read.

[This wasn't a problem last year.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254607/align-badges-by-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. I've added some padding. This will be fixed with the next production build.

Comment: So, [tag:status-completed]? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't want to mark it [tag:status-completed] until production built out. :)

Comment: Fair enough, it's just that most devs mark in advance, probably because they fear to forget to come back later. Cheers! :)